# Can an Impure Function be Referentially Transparent?

Tags: functional-programming

Is a total, impure function considered to be Referentially Transparent (RT)?

Example:

```
// Given an 'id', try to retrieve an optional Person
// from the database, i.e. side-effect.
// Note that 'String' is a poor choice for the `Left`,
// but it's not important for this question
def getPerson(id: Long): Either[String, Option[Person]] = 
    // ignore implementation
```

Assuming that `getPerson` is implemented to always return an `Either`, i.e. ignoring any fatal errors (Out of Memory, Stack Overflow, etc.), is it considered to be RT?

Perhaps the possibility of an Out of Memory or Stack Overflow error breaks RT?

I read https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/234237/72147, but I'm not sure of the answer to my question.

Comment: Is the data in the database never change (for at least the whole time the application is running, preferably even from compile-time)?

Comment: Interesting question, @CodesInChaos. Does the fact that there's a network call, i.e. my assumption that the above code needs to call a remote server via a network request, render your question irrelevant? Aside - note that I say 'irrelevant' respectfully, not to disregard your question but ask a follow-up

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The definition of RT that we use in ["the red book"](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala) is as follows:

> An expression `e` is referentially transparent if for every program
>   `p`, every occurrence of `e` in `p` can be replaced by the result of
>   evaluating `e` without affecting the meaning of `p`.

So the expression `getPerson(0)` is considered to be RT if wherever you see `getPerson(0)`, you could replace it with the result of the call.

Whether you can do this depends on the implementation. If the implementation contains an immutable map from `Long` to `Person`, and is simply a lookup in that never-changing map, then `getPerson(x)` is RT for any `x` and `getPerson` is considered a *pure function*.

If instead the call to `getPerson(x)` makes a connection to a time-varying database across a network, then the result is going to vary depending on the context. In other words, then `getPerson(x)` is *not purely a function* of `x`.

Concerning your other question, about whether OOMEs and SOEs break RT, the answer gets a bit more nuanced. You could argue that *no complex Scala expression is RT*. Consider:

```
case class Foo(s: String)
```

Now, `Foo("hello") == Foo("hello")`. But any two expressions that evaluate to `Foo("hello")` are observably different, because `Foo("hello") eq Foo("hello")` is `false`. So given the existence of `eq`, the expression `Foo("hello")` is not RT.

We'll have to alter our definition of RT a bit:

> An expression e is referentially transparent *with regard to* a program `p` if every occurrence of `e` in `p` can be replaced by the result of evaluating `e` without affecting the meaning of `p`.

With this definition, functional programming becomes an optimization problem rather than an absolute. That is, we're concerned with programming using expressions that are RT with regard to as many programs as possible.

So when we say "RT", it's really implied that we mean "RT with regard to the class of programs that don't use `eq`, or run out of memory, or dump core, or get into an infinite loop."

Comment: To elaborate on your answer, if `getPerson(0)` does IO and hits a database, it's not referentially transparent. That is, you can construct an example where `x = getPerson(0); doStuff(x); doMoreStuff(x);` is not equivalent to `doStuff(getPerson(0)); doMoreStuff(getPerson(0));` (because the database row changes in between invokations).

Comment: Put another way, if the result of `getPerson(x)` depends in any way on anything other than `x` (e.g. if it depends on the present value of some database), then it is not RT.

Answer (score 7):

Referential transparency is not some formally defined concept but

> usually means that an expression always evaluates to the same result in any context. [Source](https://wiki.haskell.org/Referential_transparency)

Here's a simple test for referential transparency for an expression `e`: does inlining a declaration of `e` change (potential) behavior?

That is, is there a difference between:

```
val x = e
doFoo(x)
doBar(x)
```

and the following

```
doFoo(e)
doBar(e)
```

In this case there is a huge difference! For example, this code will work fine:

```
val user = getPerson(32)
deleteUser(user)
displayUserDeletion(user)
```

whereas this code will blow up

```
deleteUser(getPerson(32))
displayUserDeletion(getPerson(32))
```

So this is definitely not referentially transparent. As for your second question:

> Perhaps the possibility of an Out of Memory or Stack Overflow error breaks RT?

Usually when we think of referential transparency or really any property of our programs we are thinking of them as running on perfect machines with infinite memory. This simplifying assumption is of course wrong but really necessary to get anywhere in talking about programs. Basically, stack overflow and OOM "break RT" then RT is always broken because for virtually any expression `e` there is some sufficiently tiny expression computer such that

```
val x = e
doFoo(x)
doBar(x)
```

works but

```
doFoo(e)
doFoo(e)
```

runs out of memory. To avoid referential transparency being a useless concept we have to ignore the limitation of our runtimes.

This definition also shows why we should care about RT, as it enables powerful optimizations such as Common Subexpression Elimination ([Haskell compilers do this](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC_optimisations#Common_subexpression_elimination)) where if `e` is RT we can make it so that it is only evaluated once, e.g. by transforming

```
doFoo(e)
doBar(e)
```

into

```
val x = e
doFoo(x)
doBar(x)
```

As for the question in the title, there actually are impure functions that are referentially transparent, but it's quite an unusual circumstance:

- Suppose we have a mutable object `S` that only has one method for modifying it, `S.f()`, that is is idempotent. In this case `S.f()` is impure (changes state) but is referentially transparent.

To make this more concrete suppose we have

```
class Foo {                     
  private var _x = 0
  def this(x: Int) { this(); _x = x }
  def x = _x
  def setXToFive(): Unit = {
    _x = 5
  } 
}
```

Here if `foo : Foo`, `foo.setXToFive()` is referentially transparent.

Comment: @Apocalisp, to some extent this is quibbling over definitions for something that is not well defined (I generally agree with the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865616/purity-vs-referential-transparency?rq=1). To have a useful distinction between the two I am using RT as "replaceable with its definition", which `S.f()` is even in this case (take `foo() = { var x = 0; return x + ((()=>(x = 1))() + x); }`).

Comment: I'm confused, what does it mean for a statement (i.e. an expression of type `Unit`) to be referentially transparent? That you can replace its invokation with its result, which is... `Unit`? (I'm talking about your example).

Comment: @AndresF.: Well, if an expression returns `Unit`, you normally execute it for its side-effects, otherwise it would be useless. So, I doubt that any pure function that returns `Unit` can be of any use.

Comment: "Haskell compilers do this": the cited text says that Haskell compilers perform this rather seldom: "GHC doesn't actually perform CSE as often as you might expect. The trouble is, performing CSE can affect the strictness/laziness of the program. So GHC does do CSE, but only in specific circumstances --- see the GHC manual." [reference missing]

Comment: Referential transparency is formally defined: it means that an expression can be replaced with its value without changing the meaning of any program.

Comment: @Giorgio That's what I was aiming at :) And since the example is a statement, I'm not sure the term "referentially transparent" is meaningful. Idempotent is better.

Answer (score 0):

No. An impure function cannot be referentially transparent by definition*. The function you gave is not pure. Writing a function to return `Either` does not automatically make it pure. It still does not always return the same value for the same input. If the function you gave accepted a `person` parameter *and* a `database`/`lookup` parameter, then the function would be pure and referentially transparent, because if given the same referentially transparent `database` / `lookup`, it would always return the same value.

In regards to fatal errors (Out of Memory, Stack Overflow, etc.), I guess, yes? You can be pedantic and say *technically*, no function or program is pure because the machines running could break down. Somebody could just pull the power cord. But then no function is `pure` / `referentially transparent` and those terms lose all meaning...

*`An expression e is referentially transparent if for every program p, every occurrence of e in p can be replaced by the result of evaluating e without affecting the meaning of p.`